# Bounded sequence of real numbers and convergent subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $(|x_{n}(\alpha_{k}^n)|)_n$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers , for  each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (meaning $|x_{n}(\alpha_{k}^n)| \leq M$ for one constant $M$ and all $n,k$) such that for fixed $n,$ the sequence on $k$ decreases: $|x_n(\alpha_1^n)|\geq |x_n(\alpha_2^n)|\geq \ldots.$

I'm trying to prove that there is one convergent subsequence for all at once $k.$

I see that for each $k$ there is a convergent subsequence $(|x_{n_{s_k}}(\alpha_{k}^{n_{s_k}})|)_n$ converging to some $\zeta_k$ as $s_k \to \infty.$

But i wish to write at once $\lim\limits_{l \to \infty} |x_{n_l}(\alpha_{k}^{n_l})| =: z(k), k \in \mathbb{N}$ and since this one subsequence will clearly be also decreasing on $k$ after taking limit in those inequality we would obtain $z(1)\geq z(2) \geq \ldots.$

My thinking was the following: i will denote this sequence by $a_n^k.$
First $k=1$ and we have convergent subsequence $(a_{n_{l_1}}^1)_{l_1=1}^{\infty}$ converging to some $\zeta_1$ when $l_1 \to \infty.$
Then i'm looking at $k=2$ with theese indicies $n_{l_1}$ for $l_1 = 1,2,..$
I.e. for $(a_{n_{l_1}}^2)_{l_1=1}^{\infty}$ there is convergent subsequence $(a_{n_{l_2}}^2)_{l_1=2}^{\infty}$ converging to some $\zeta_2$ as $l_2 \to \infty.$
Now we for only those indicies we have one convergent subsequence $((a_{n_{l_2}}^k)_{l_2=1}^{\infty}$ for both $k=1,2.$ And proceeding as this for all $k \in \mathbb{N}.$ My concern is that with this construction i can obtain only for any finite number of $k$ but not for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ at once.

Comment: Are you familiar with the diagonal method ?

Answer (score 0):

For $k=1$ choose a convergent subsequence $\{a_{j_{s}^{(1)}}^1\}_{s<\omega}.$
For $k=2$ now only considering those indecies $j_{1}^{(1)}<j_{2}^{(1)}<\ldots$ choose a convergent subsequence of $\{a_{j_{s}^{(1)}}^2\}_{s<\omega}$ and denote it by $\{a_{j_{s}^{(2)}}^2\}_{s<\omega}.$ Now for $\{j_s^{(2)}\}_{s < \omega}$ we have that both $\{ a_{j_{s}^{(2)}}^1 \}_{s<\omega}$ and $\{ a_{j_{s}^{(2)}}^2 \}_{s<\omega}$ are convergent subsequences simultaneously for $k=1,2.$ Note also that $\{ j_{s}^{(2)} \}_{s<\omega} \subset \{ j_{s}^{(1)} \}_{s<\omega}$ as we used the indicies from the first step.

For $k=m$, we have chosen  convergent subsequences $\{a_{j_s^{(m)}}^1\}_{s<\omega}, \{a_{j_s^{(m)}}^2\}_{s<\omega}, \ldots, \{a_{j_s^{(m)}}^m\}_{s<\omega}$ simultaneously for $k=1,2,\ldots,m.$ And having that

$$\{ j_{s}^{(1)} \}_{s<\omega} \supset \{ j_{s}^{(2)} \}_{s<\omega} \supset \ldots \supset \{j_{s}^{(m)}\}_{s<\omega}$$

For $k=m+1,$ considering $\{a_{j_{s}^{(m)}}^{m+1}\}_{s<\omega}$ we choose it's convergent subsequence $\{a_{j_{s}^{(m+1)}}^{m+1}\}_{s<\omega}$ and still $\{j_{s}^{(m+1)}\}_{s<\omega} \subset \{j_{s}^{(m)}\}$ and so are contained in all  of the previous indicies.

Now trying to do a diagonal argument we set $i_1:=j_{1}^{(1)}$ and so on $i_{s}:=j_{s}^{(s)}, s \in \omega$ and for an arbitrary $k \in \omega$ considering the subsequence $\{a_{i_s}^k\}_{s<\omega}=\{a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_k}\}\cup \{a_{i_s}^k\}_{s>k}.$ Since $\{i_{k+1},i_{k+2},\ldots\}$ are contained in all of the "above indicies" , the are contained in particular in $\{j_{s}^{(k)}\}_{s<\omega}$ which gave convergent subsequence $\{a_{j_{s}^{(k)}}^k\}_{s<\omega}$ and $\{a_{i_s}^k\}_{s>k} \subset \{a_{j_{s}^{(k)}}^k\}_{s<\omega}$ it's subsequence, so is too convergent.
And thus $\{a_{i_s}^k\}_{s<\omega}$ is convergent for each $k \in \omega.$